# Making a launcher for a command

Tags: launcher, command-line, steam

How to execute a command just by clicking a shortcut on the desktop. I'm still very new to linux, this would help alot. Like for example I want to run steam.exe without no dwrite, so the command is 'wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite' and i want to be able to execute this command by just clicking a shortcut on the desktop. I think it is a shell script maybe? I dunno, like i said, i am new, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a .desktop file for that.

Open 'gedit' and copy and paste the following layout

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Steam
Comment=Access Steam via Wine
Exec=wine /actual/path/to/Steam.exe -no-dwrite
Icon=/path/to/your/steam/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Games;
StartupNotify=true
```

You find the actual path to your 'Steam.exe somewhere in the .wine folder in your home directory
(it's a hidden folder so to make it visible you have to press 'ctrl + h' inside your home directory).
Then you have to put that path where I put '/actual/path/to/steam.exe'.

For the icon just insert the path of the steam icon where I put '/path/to/your/steam/icon'.

Now save the file as  Steam.desktop and close gedit.
Right-click on your newly created Steam.desktop select properties
 and in the Permissions tab tick the 'mark as executable' field.
Now it should be just called Steam and the selected icon should be visible.